# Shared Hosting that allow use as backup

Tags: linux, backup, web-hosting, rsync

I have been looking around for a while and I can't seem to find a shared web host that will allow me to backup my offsite data nightly (using rsync).  I am using the host itself to do development work on a clone of that site that I am backing up.

Anyone know if one of these even exist?  If not, a really cheap backup solution that will allow me to transfer 2-4gigs nightly (only need latest copy)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try http://rsync.net/ - they've been around for quite some time and the price is quite equitable, and then you won't have to dance around TOS issues.

That being said, slap up a faux website over 2-4GB of content, and lots of shared hosts will probably not notice you shuffling off content via rsync as long as your initial transfer goes through and you're only pushing through the diffs.

Answer (score 1):

OK.  I have found out that Dreamhost offers personal backup space 50gig with their accounts and allow rsync. This is the wiki http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Personal_Backup

Is this the only host that provides / allows this?

Comment: Word on the street is that these backup servers are down quite a bit...

Answer (score 0):

If you can ssh you can run [rsync over ssh](http://troy.jdmz.net/rsync/index.html) to do the backup. There are a lot of cheap hosts that will let you ssh in.

Comment: Thats what I want to do, it just seems to violate everyones TOS to store backups from remote sites.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a VPS?  [Slicehost](http://www.slicehost.com/) gives you 10GB storage and 100GB bandwidth for $20 a month.  You can use rsync, store whatever data you want on the server, and it's all part of the T&C's.

Comment: I will take a look at slicehost for other projects.  I am looking for more of the $10 range for this one.  Thanks.